# Custom Timer Picker IOS Clock

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, uikit

I want to customise the appearance of timer picker of clock app in iOS (Basically it's an UIDatePicker with timer mode). I want to change the text color and border line color of picker, but as per the documentation it's not possible to customise the appearance. Can anyone has the method to customise the picker.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can customize datepicker something like,

**Objective c :**

```
targetedDatePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[targetedDatePicker setValue:[UIColor greenColor] forKey:@"textColor"];

[targetedDatePicker setValue:@"0.8" forKey:@"alpha"];
```

**Swift :**

```
targetedDatePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
targetedDatePicker.setValue(UIColor.greenColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
targetedDatePicker.setValue(0.8, forKeyPath: "alpha")
```

so, you can customize datepicker appearance like this

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This method works for IPad, but for IPhone it doesn't work